# How to get controller list size in javscript function

Tags: visualforce, javascript, list, alert

I am trying to display an alert based on list size.But list size is not getting passed inside javascript function here

```
    <apex:outputPanel  id='size'>
    <script>
    function checkListSize(){

      var eterm={!SelectedAccounts.size};

        if(eterm > 3){

      alert('Please Select 6 Accounts');
        }
    }
    </script>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

/************Account list*************/

```
<apex:dataTable value="{!accountList}" var="a" columnswidth="50px,50px"
                                cellpadding="4" border="1"  id="acctable" styleClass="a-table">
                    <apex:column headerValue="Select Account" style="{!IF((a.acc.Master_Record__c ='MasterRecord'),"background-color: #D3D3D3;","")}" >
                       <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!a.selected}" id="checkedone" >
                           <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" action="{!GetSelected}"
                                                rerender="Selected_PBS"   status="loadStatus" >
```

/************Selected Account list*************/

```
                <apex:dataTable value="{!SelectedAccounts}" var="s"
                                columnswidth="50px,50px" cellpadding="4" border="1" id="selectedones" >
```

/***********Calling function in this button************/

```
<apex:commandButton onclick="doControllerSave()" value="Combine Accounts" oncomplete="checkListSize();" reRender="Size" style="background:#D3D3D3;width:150px;" status="loadStatus" disabled="{!If(SelectedAccounts!= null && SelectedAccounts.size > 1,false, true)}"  />
```

controller

```
    public list<Account> selectedAccounts
    {get;set;}
 public PageReference getSelected() 
    {
        selectedAccounts=new list<Account>();
        list<Account> newselected = new list<Account>();
        System.debug('Selected account list'+accountList);
        system.debug('accountId'+apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('accId'));
        string accountId = apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('accId');
        for(accountwrapper accwrapper : accountList) 
        { 
            if(accwrapper.acc.id == accountId ) {


                if(accwrapper.selected==true) 
                { 

                    selectedsets.add(accwrapper.acc); 
                    system.debug('setttt'+selectedsets); 

                }

                else    {
                bool=false;
                    selectedsets.remove(accwrapper.acc);

                }
            }

        } 

selectedAccounts.addall(selectedsets);


        System.debug('selectedAccountsss'+selectedAccounts);
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Is it null or are you just not getting an alert. You are comparing a string to an integer. What if you change the 3 to '3'. If it is null then at what point is selected accounts populated. If not on page instantiation the value in js will not change unless you use an output panel to rerender and set the value of a js var on completion of your action that populated sekectedaccounts. Then use that var in you js

Comment: Just to add on to @Eric comment, javascript is case-sensitive so you need to change `Alert('...')` to `alert('..')` for it to work properly. And how are you even invoking this `checkListSize()` function?

Comment: @Eric its null.I have updated the question to understand on where selected accounts is being invoked and where I am calling script function.

Comment: Ok then you will have to to what I stated if it was null. Outputoanel with script that declares a var equal to the value of selectedaccounts.size. Rerender that panel on complete of your action. Use that js var in your current method and then call it.

Comment: @Anamadeya,Changed.Still I dint get it

Comment: @Pri can you show us your controller code on how you get SelectedAccounts, plz?

Comment: Updated@Lance Shi

Comment: @Eric.I have updated my script and added rerender attribute in command button.As specified in updated question.Is that right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the steps to resolve you problem:

1. Make sure `selectedAccounts` is initilized in controller constructor like

   `selectedAccounts= new List<Account> ()`;
2. Use below block at top of your page:

   `<apex:outputpanel id="varAssignmentPanel">
       <Script>
        var eterm;
        if(isNaN('{!SelectedAccounts.size}')==false){
            eterm=parseInt('{!SelectedAccounts.size}') ;
            }
       // alert(eterm);  //use this alert to check variable assignment
       </Script>
   </apex:outputpanel>`

The purpose of this block is to declare your eterm variable as global and it should not be declared as local to your function.

3. Now change your command button as

`<apex:commandButton onclick="doControllerSave()" value="Combine Accounts" oncomplete="checkListSize();" reRender="Size,varAssignmentPanel" style="background:#D3D3D3;width:150px;" status="loadStatus" disabled="{!If(SelectedAccounts!= null && SelectedAccounts.size > 1,false, true)}"  />`

If your controller code is working fine you should be able to get alert properly now.

Comment: ,Yeah I am getting the value.But what will "isNaN" do?

Comment: isNaN is Javascript function that gets a parameter and tells if supplied parameter is not a number. I used this in order to make sure to use conversion into integer only when non null value is available.